# Please make the site search on the API alphabetical

Tags: feature-request, documentation

When I search, I want the sites to be alphabetical:

[image]

Please can they be?

Answer (score 4):

If this doesn't happen, this simple script will do it for you!:

```
$('.site-picker.ui-autocomplete-input').on('input', function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var mylist = $('body > ul.ui-autocomplete');
        var listitems = mylist.children('li').get();
        listitems.sort(function(a, b) {
            return $(a).text().toUpperCase().localeCompare($(b).text().toUpperCase());
        })
        $.each(listitems, function(idx, itm) { mylist.append(itm); });
    }, 500);
});
```

The main sorting part's code is from https://stackoverflow.com/a/1134983/3541881! Please +1 his answer!

As a userscript [over here](https://github.com/shu8/SE-Answers_scripts/raw/master/alphabeticalSiteSearchAPI.user.js).

[image]